# How to select a jQuery element's child with one selector?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have an `div` with the `id` `article_50`.
If I were to select the `.title` element inside `article_50`, I could do the following:
`$("#article_50 .title")`.

Now say I want to select that same title, but within a click event:

```
$("#article_50").click(function(){
    $(this).children(".title").hide();
});
```

Now I had to call the `children` method to select that `.title` element.
Could I select it within the same selector without the need to call `children`?

Something like this:

`$("this .title").hide();`

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Almost there:

```
$(".title", this).hide();
```

Comment: +1 for the correct answer, but I think it is less "readable" than $(this).children(".title").hide();

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#article_50").click(function(){ $(".title", this).hide(); });
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `.children()` if the `.title` element is actually a child of `this`.

When you do:

```
$(".title", this).hide();
```

...jQuery has to run 7 or 8 tests before it figures out that you're looking for `.title` inside of `this`.

Then jQuery just flips it around into this:

```
$(this).find('.title')
```

...and starts over. So it is calling a method anyway after all that testing. As you can see it is not very efficient.

Also, because `.children()` only looks one level deep, it is faster to use `.children()` than `.find()` if your element is actually a child.

---

**EDIT:**

An even faster way would be to cache the `#article_50` element in a variable, so you don't need to create a jQuery object for `$(this)` every time you click.

```
var $art_50 = $("#article_50").click(function(){
    $art_50.children(".title").hide();
});

// Now you have a variable that you can use outside the click handler as well
//   in case you are selecting it elsewhere in your code.
```

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't you just be able to say:

```
$("#article_50").click(function(){ $("#article_50 .title").hide(); });
```

That's nearly the same and you don't need to call children.

Comment: absolutely, but if instead of a specific ID i had a class, and several  elements of that class in the page, i'd be forced to use `this` to identify it. good point, though!